# JQuery ScrollTo Conflict

Tags: jquery-plugins, scrollto, jplayer

I have built a site that uses jquery and 3 plugins...

1. jquery.lightbox-0.5
2. ScrollTo
3. jPlayer

I continue to have some sort of conflict between my jPlayer script and the ScrollTo script.
Without jPlayer the ScrollTo script works fine.  But when I add jPlayer the ScrollTo function scrolls the page to the selected div but then returns the scroll to the top of the page rather than staying on that selected div.

Could someone help me understand what the conflict is.  Can I use both these scripts on the same page.

Here is the site I am working on.

http://www.multiplydivide.com/colm/mainorder.html#

Comment: I updated to the latest version of both jquery.scrollTo-min.js and jquery.scrollTo.js.  Worked fine then.

Answer (score 2):

I updated to the latest version of both jquery.scrollTo-min.js and jquery.scrollTo.js. Worked fine then.